# Android, Is it possible to some how split a listview into two horizontal coumns

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

Is it possibly to take a single list view which in portrait view would normally be displayed normally, but when in landscape mode I wan the list view to be split into to two entities one next to each other.

I have attached an image to try and explain what I would Like.

[image]

How can I achieve this without having to put two separate interviews next to each other?

Comment: Use different layout for landscape mode and portrait mode.

Comment: I am doing that already, But as the question says, the issue is splitting the listview.

Comment: What do you mean by *splitting the listview*? Did you mean splitting the data and use the same item layout for both `ListView`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a `GridView`. This is very close to a `ListView` More information [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html).

Use `android:numColumns="2"` for set the column number.

here some help : [Column number regarding orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18850704/dynamically-change-column-number-in-android-gridview)

Hope is what you want.

Comment: Great Solution, So simple and so easy.